# featureclass legend

Tags: arcmap, legend

Is there any way to specify a legend before I attribute a featureclass in ARCMAP 10? I have a featureclass layer that has many thousands of polygons, I have to go through and individually attribute them, but it would be great if I could pre-define the symbology such that as I attribute polygons they will be filled in. More importantly, there will be approximately 150 different fill colors, I would like to be able to import the rgb values from a table, rather than manually input the values.

Answer (score 2):

That is called creating attribute domain values. That is supported in geodatabases (any level).
[A Quick Tour of Attribute Domains](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001s00000001000000.htm)

After you create a domain and assign it to a layer then you would want to create a feature template for editing.

Comment: @Gabriele When you find a reply useful, please vote it up.  When it's a great, or at least the most useful reply, please mark it accepted.  Doing these things enhances your reputation and increases the value of the replies for other people.